How to swap WordPress wp:navigation on mobile devices
I'm using WP twenty-twenty four theme with a child theme that uses page templates and a header part.
Within the header part I have the following to populate it with the navigation
<!-- wp:group {"style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"top":"2rem","bottom":"2rem","right":"2rem","left":"2rem"}}},"layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group tan-header">
    <!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"flex","justifyContent":"space-between"}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group">
        <div><img src="http://217.199.187.191/tanzaniaodyssey.com/wp-content/themes/tanzaniatheme/images/tanzania-logo-off-white.svg"></div>
        <div>
        <!-- wp:navigation {"ref":5,"icon":"menu","layout":{"type":"flex","setCascadingProperties":true,"justifyContent":"right"},"className":"taz-menu"} /-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

This is fine and is showing the menu I want displayed for desktop users. However, I would like to have an alternative menu shown to mobile users.
I've tried using media breakpoints using a class in the div's but the two wp:navigation show - it seems to ignore the styling on the parent div.
Does anyone have any ideas how I can switch out the menu's for mobile devices?
I tried the following with a class to hide the div's depending on the media breakpoint in the style sheet. The result was both nav bars were present in the header but the layout was messed up.
<!-- wp:group {"style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"top":"2rem","bottom":"2rem","right":"2rem","left":"2rem"}}},"layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group tan-header">
    <!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"flex","justifyContent":"space-between"}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group">
        <div><img src="http://217.199.187.191/tanzaniaodyssey.com/wp-content/themes/tanzaniatheme/images/tanzania-logo-off-white.svg"></div>
        <div class="nav-desktop">
        <!-- wp:navigation {"ref":5,"icon":"menu","layout":{"type":"flex","setCascadingProperties":true,"justifyContent":"right"},"className":"taz-menu"} /-->
        </div>

<div class="nav-mobile">
        <!-- wp:navigation {"ref":1591,"icon":"menu","layout":{"type":"flex","setCascadingProperties":true,"justifyContent":"right"},"className":"taz-menu"} /-->
        </div>


    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

